# Mongodb collection.Find() returning filtered data

Tags: mongodb, go

I want to bring the `user_id: 1` ones under the users with the codes I give below, but the results are always empty.

I am not getting any errors, but I do not fully understand where I am making mistakes :/

*In addition;

What is `bson.M{}` What is `bson.D{}`. I did not fully understand what the differences are between?

```golang
type Project struct {
    ID          string          `json:"id"`
    ProjectName string          `json:"project_name"`
    Tags        []ProjectTags   `json:"tags"`
    Type        int             `json:"type"`
    Constituent string          `json:"constituent"`
    CoverPhoto  string          `json:"cover_photo"`
    Ratio       string          `json:"ratio"`
    Width       string          `json:"width"`
    Height      string          `json:"height"`
    User        []ProjectUsers  `json:"users"`
    CreatedAt   time.Time       `json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt   time.Time       `json:"updated_at"`
}

type ProjectTags struct {
    TagName string `json:"tag_name"`
    Order   int    `json:"order"`
}

type ProjectUsers struct {
    UserID string `json:"user_id"`
}
```

```golang
import (
    "context"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
)

type projectListResponse struct {
    Status          int       `json:"status"`
    Description     string    `json:"description"`
    DatabaseMessage string    `json:"database_message"`
    Projects        []Project `json:"projects"`
}

func ProjectList(c *gin.Context) {
    projects := []Project{}
    cursor, err :=  (context.TODO(), bson.M{"users": bson.M{"$elemMatch": bson.M{"user_id": "1"}}})
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, &projectListResponse{
            Status:          http.StatusInternalServerError,
            Description:     "There is problems with listing projects",
            DatabaseMessage: err.Error(),
            Projects:        projects,
        })
        return
    }
    for cursor.Next(context.TODO()) {
        var project Project
        cursor.Decode(&project)
        projects = append(projects, project)
    }
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, &projectListResponse{
        Status:          http.StatusOK,
        Description:     "All registered projects are listed successfully",
        DatabaseMessage: "No error",
        Projects:        projects,
    })
    return
}
```

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "description": "All registered projects are listed successfully",
    "database_message": "No error",
    "projects": [
        {
            "id": "000000000000000000000000",
            "project_name": "Testxx 123",
            "tags": [
                {
                    "tag_name": "asdasd",
                    "order": 1
                }
            ],
            "type": 1,
            "constituent": "1",
            "cover_photo": "",
            "ratio": "x",
            "width": "100",
            "height": "200",
            "users": [
                {
                    "user_id": "1"
                },
                {
                    "user_id": "2"
                }
            ],
            "created_at": "2020-07-07T12:10:06.861Z",
            "updated_at": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        {
            "id": "000000000000000000000000",
            "project_name": "Test 12233",
            "tags": [
                {
                    "tag_name": "asdasd",
                    "order": 1
                }
            ],
            "type": 1,
            "constituent": "1",
            "cover_photo": "",
            "ratio": "x",
            "width": "100",
            "height": "200",
            "users": [
                {
                    "user_id": "1"
                },
                {
                    "user_id": "2"
                }
            ],
            "created_at": "2020-07-07T12:10:29.394Z",
            "updated_at": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        {
            "id": "000000000000000000000000",
            "project_name": "Test 12233",
            "tags": [
                {
                    "tag_name": "asdasd",
                    "order": 1
                }
            ],
            "type": 1,
            "constituent": "1",
            "cover_photo": "",
            "ratio": "x",
            "width": "100",
            "height": "200",
            "users": [
                {
                    "user_id": "5"
                },
                {
                    "user_id": "2"
                }
            ],
            "created_at": "2020-07-07T12:10:29.394Z",
            "updated_at": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: https://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo/bson#D

Comment: @AyushGupta mgo is the wrong package, MongoDB has official Go Driver here: https://pkg.go.dev/mod/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.3.4

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to connect first your MongoDB client, if your go application starts:

   clientOptions := options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://localhost:27017")
   client, err := mongo.Connect(context.TODO(), clientOptions)
2. Get connected MongoDB client for query:

   collection := client.Database("DATABASE").Collection("COLLECTION")
   cur, err := collection.Find(context.TODO(), bson.D{{}}, findOptions)

You have only the query in your code. You have no results because you don't have database and collection for collection.Find():

```
   cursor, err :=  (context.TODO(), bson.M{"users": bson.M{"$elemMatch": bson.M{"user_id": "1"}}})
```

[MongoDB Go Driver Tutorial](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-go-driver-tutorial) is very good start point for CRUD operations. MongoDB driver bson type descriptions from Go Driver Tutorial:

```
D: A BSON document. This type should be used in situations where order matters, such as MongoDB commands.
M: An unordered map. It is the same as D, except it does not preserve order.
A: A BSON array.
E: A single element inside a D.
```

You can check official MongoDB Go Driver packages for [bson here](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.3.4/bson?tab=doc).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, MongoDB connects when the application is running.

```golang
func main() {
    mongoDB()
    server := routerV1()
    server.Run(os.Getenv("PORT"))
}
```

```golang
var collection *mongo.Collection

func dashboard(c *mongo.Database) {
    collection = c.Collection("dashboard")
}

func mongoDB() {
    // Database Config
    clientOptions := options.Client().ApplyURI(os.Getenv("MONGODB"))
    client, err := mongo.NewClient(clientOptions)
    // Set up a context required by mongo.Connect
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    err = client.Connect(ctx)
    // To close the connection at the end
    defer cancel()
    err = client.Ping(context.Background(), readpref.Primary())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Couldn't connect to the database", err)
    }
    mongoDB := client.Database("databasename")
    dashboard(mongoDB)
    return
}
```

When I make my query like this, all data is returned.

```golang
cursor, err := collection.Find(context.TODO(), bson.M{})
```

Problem; The empty result returns when I filter to return "users: [" user_id ":" 1 "]".

```golang
cursor, err := collection.Find(context.TODO(), bson.M{"users": bson.M{"$elemMatch": bson.M{"user_id": "1"}}})
```

As I said, there is no problem in the connection. When I do not filter, all results are returned. When I filter the way I want, the empty result is returned.

When I do the filtering I want to do on the command line on mongo, I can get the result I want.

Thank You